# Basic proof regarding algebra of sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

An algebra of sets has the following properties (the universe is $X$):

(i) $\emptyset \in \mathcal{A}$
(ii) If $A \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A^c \in \mathcal{A}$ (all complements are with the respect to the universe $X$, hence $A^c= X \setminus A)$.
(iii) If $A,B \in \mathcal{A}$, then $A \cup B \in \mathcal{A}$

Show that $X \in \mathcal{A}$

My solution:

Take some $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$, then according to (ii), $A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$. According to (iii), if $A_i,A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$ then $A_i \cup A_i^c \in \mathcal{A}$, so $X \in \mathcal{A}$.

(The task didn't say anything about indexing the family of sets, but I take it for granted that one always could do that...?)

(I just wanted to confirm if my math-reasoning is correct, because I don't have any teacher... :) Perhaps later on I will take this book for an exam, but I have to see if I will master if... or at least do OK.)

Comment: Your notation is not good. You should say $A \in \mathcal{A}$ instead of $A_i \in \mathcal{A}$. No need fo any indexing.

Comment: Let $A$ be random, then?

Comment: $A=\emptyset \implies A^c = X \in \mathbb A. $

Comment: I liked that one, @TurlocTheRed

Comment: Note that your proof is not quite complete. You only use (ii) and (iii), but $\mathcal{A}$ is a perfectly satisfactory model of (ii) and (iii) with $X\notin\mathcal{A}$. For your proof to work, you need to show that there is $A\in\mathcal{A}$ to begin with. However, (i) lets you do this (though at that point @TurlocTheRed 's proof is much simpler).

Comment: Thanks, Calliope! I must also show that there is an $A$, and by (i) there is.